# modal popup bootstrap 5 not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-5

the popup modal from BS5 is not showing on mobile,, but on desktop is working fine
here is the code

```
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

idk if i'm missing something or not,, any idea how to fix that?

Comment: try using chromes developer option and go to mobile view and check the console afterwards
that should give you a clear picture as to why its not working in mobile version

Comment: there's nothing error on the console dev, for you is that working normally?

Comment: Check modal is hidden in css or incorrectly positioned

Comment: there is no overriding the modal class in my css,, for html code is pure copy from BS 5 doc, no change from it